# Problema con servidor server lync

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-office

Hola tengo instalado Microsoft Lync en un servidor y tengo un problema importante y no me deja dar de alta nuevos usuarios. Los usuarios que ya tengo creados, pueden funcionar sin ningun problema, el programa surge cuando quiero acceder al panel de control e intento crear usuarios nuevos. El mensaje que estoy adjuntando sale cuando entro a la consola de panel de control. Por favo pido vuestra colaboración para ver si me podéis ayudar.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido Francisco. Para poder ser ayudado de la mejor manera en este sitio te recomiendo que leas algunas normas sobre cómo preguntar: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking De entrada, evita añadir imágenes, es más útil que copies y pegues en tu pregunta el texto de los mensajes de error que te está dando, etc.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es una pregunta acerca de programación o falta la información suficiente para evaluar el código.

Comment: Hola Francisco, además del enlace que te proporciona @A.Cedano, podría ser útil que revisaras cómo aportar un [mcve] o te pasaras por el [tour]. Bienvenido a SO en español.